# Justify an approximation of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty G_n/\binom{\frac{n}{2}+\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{n}{2}}$, where $G_n$ denotes the Gregory coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients, analytic-number-theory

While I was playing with an integral posted in Math Oveflow, I wondered a different question using a CAS, and one of those answers posted, see [1]. My combination is to create a series involving the so-called Gregory coefficients $G_n$, see this [Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregory_coefficients)

> **Question.** Is it possible to justify an (a reasonably good) approximation of $$I=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{G_n}{\binom{\frac{n}{2}+\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{n}{2}}}\,?$$ **Thanks in advance.**

Thus that I am asking is how one can to justify an approxiation of $I$ using analysis or analytic number theory. There are no more context for this question, only the idea about how to get such good approximation that I evoke (I can get the approximation $I\approx 0.35305$, but I don't know how justify it).

### References:

[1] The answer from T. Amdeberhan of [*A curious sin-integral*](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/272381/a-curious-sin-integral), MathOverflow (2017).

Comment: Many thanks for your attention and feedback @YuriyS Feel free to add your approach to get an approximation of our series.

Comment: I'm not sure if my answer would be useful (it's not an approximation), but I hope it might be

Comment: I wonder why did you decide to use Gregory coefficients here, since the original series just contained $(-1)^n$ together with the binomial

Comment: (1/2) First many thanks for sharing the calculations of your answer, I hope that users will do feedback and uptove your answer, that has a great merit and precision. Secondly was a exploration about this sequence. I'm interested in the prime approach about unsolved problems. It is known that Bernoulli numbers are related with the Riemann Zeta, as you know and I refer the section *A restatement of the Riemann hypothesis*, from the Wikipedia's article dedicated to the Bernoulli numbers, also are related to prime numbers as tell me the Wikipedia's article dedicated to the Agoh–Giuga conjecture.

Comment: (2/2) Now I know, also from an informative point of view this second sequence, the Gregory coefficients. Wikipedia's article for Gregory coefficients refers (a less number) of formulas related to the Riemann's Zeta and the Euler-Mascheroni constant, $li(x)$, but not prime numbers (likes as Agoh–Giuga conjecture). Thus it seems mysterious to me. Then I try to ask series, sequences or funcions related to Gregory coefficients changing other that were in the literature to try elucidate something. But my exploration isn't scientific. Many thanks @YuriyS

Comment: In this case, of course I accept that yes the original series, with $(-1)^n$ ins't related to unsolved problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some results on expressing this series through hypergeometric functions.

First, we rewrite the sum using Gamma functions:

$$I=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\Gamma \left( \frac{n}{2}+1 \right)}{\Gamma \left( \frac{n}{2}+\frac{3}{2} \right)} G_n=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \frac{\Gamma \left( \frac{n}{2}+1 \right)}{\Gamma \left( \frac{n}{2}+\frac{3}{2} \right)} |G_n|$$

Here we also use the fact that $G_n$ have alternating signs.

Now the main idea is to separate even and odd terms, which is necessary to be able to use hypergeometric functions. Let's introduce two new series:

$$S_1=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\Gamma \left(k+ \frac{1}{2} \right)}{\Gamma \left( k+1 \right)} G_{2k-1} >0$$

$$S_2=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\Gamma \left(k+ 1 \right)}{\Gamma \left( k+\frac{3}{2} \right)} G_{2k} <0$$

$$I= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} (S_1+S_2)$$

---

Let us use one of the integral expressions for $G_n$:

$$G_n=\int_0^1 \binom{x}{n} dx=\int_0^1 \frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{n! \Gamma(x-n+1)}dx$$

---

For $S_1$ we have:

$$S_1=\int_0^1 \Gamma(x+1) dx \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\Gamma \left(k+ \frac{1}{2} \right)}{\Gamma \left( k+1 \right) \Gamma(2k) \Gamma(x-2k+2)}$$

Let's call the inner sum $Q_1$ and change the index $k \to k+1$, then:

$$Q_1=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma \left(k+ \frac{3}{2} \right)}{\Gamma \left( k+2 \right) \Gamma(2k+2) \Gamma(x-2k)}$$

To find the hypergeometric form of this series, we should consider the ratio of general terms:

$$t_0=\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{3}{2} \right)}{\Gamma (x)}$$

$$\frac{t_{k+1}}{t_k}=\frac{\left(k+ \frac{3}{2} \right) (x-2k-1)(x-2k-2)}{(k+2)(2k+3)(2k+2)}=\frac{\left(k+ \frac{1}{2}- \frac{x}{2}  \right) \left(k+ 1- \frac{x}{2}  \right)}{(k+2)} \frac{1}{k+1}$$

By definition this means:

$$Q_1=\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{3}{2} \right)}{\Gamma (x)} {_2 F_1} \left(\frac{1}{2}- \frac{x}{2},1- \frac{x}{2};2;1  \right)$$

---

For $S_2$ we have:

$$S_2=\int_0^1 \Gamma(x+1) dx \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\Gamma \left(k+ 1 \right)}{\Gamma \left( k+\frac{3}{2} \right) \Gamma(2k+1) \Gamma(x-2k+1)}$$

Let's call the inner sum $Q_2$ and change the index $k \to k+1$, then:

$$Q_2=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma \left(k+ 2 \right)}{\Gamma \left( k+\frac{5}{2} \right) \Gamma(2k+3) \Gamma(x-2k-1)}$$

To find the hypergeometric form of this series, we should consider the ratio of general terms:

$$t_0=\frac{1}{2 \Gamma \left(\frac{5}{2} \right) \Gamma (x-1)}$$

$$\frac{t_{k+1}}{t_k}=\frac{\left(k+ 2\right) (x-2k-2)(x-2k-3)}{\left(k+\frac{5}{2} \right)(2k+4)(2k+3)}=\frac{(k+1)\left(k+ \frac{3}{2}- \frac{x}{2}  \right) \left(k+ 1- \frac{x}{2}  \right)}{\left(k+\frac{3}{2} \right) \left(k+\frac{5}{2} \right)} \frac{1}{k+1}$$

By definition this means:

$$Q_2=\frac{1}{2 \Gamma \left(\frac{5}{2} \right) \Gamma (x-1)} {_3 F_2} \left(1, \frac{3}{2}- \frac{x}{2},1- \frac{x}{2};\frac{3}{2},\frac{5}{2};1  \right)$$

---

Now let us collect the results (with some simple transforms based on Gamma function properties):

> $$S_1=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \int_0^1 x ~{_2 F_1} \left(\frac{1}{2}- \frac{x}{2},1- \frac{x}{2};2;1  \right) dx $$
>
> $$S_2=- \frac{2}{3 \sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^1 x(1-x) ~{_3 F_2} \left(1, \frac{3}{2}- \frac{x}{2},1- \frac{x}{2};\frac{3}{2},\frac{5}{2};1  \right) dx $$

$$I= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} (S_1+S_2)$$

> $$I=\frac{\pi}{4} \int_0^1 x ~{_2 F_1} \left(\frac{1}{2}- \frac{x}{2},1- \frac{x}{2};2;1  \right) dx- \\ - \frac{1}{3 } \int_0^1 x(1-x) ~{_3 F_2} \left(1, \frac{3}{2}- \frac{x}{2},1- \frac{x}{2};\frac{3}{2},\frac{5}{2};1  \right) dx$$

The numerical values of the integrals, computed by Mathematica with working precision set to 100, lead to:

$$I = 0.353056313931150786257841734863968642813 \dots$$

Which is in good agreement with the value proposed by the OP.

The original sum computed for $996-999$ terms leads to:

$$I_{996}=\color{blue}{0.35305}5994793\dots \\ I_{997}=\color{blue}{0.353056}632513\dots \\ I_{998}=\color{blue}{0.35305}5995902\dots \\ I_{999}=\color{blue}{0.353056}631407\dots$$

The arithmetic mean of succesive even and odd terms gives better approximation, but not by much.

So the convergence is really bad. I suspect it could be accelerated by the usual techniques (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_acceleration), meanwhile the integrals provide the accurate value.

---

**Note:** Using another integral formula:

$$G_n=(-1)^{n+1} \int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{(1+x)^n (\ln^2 x+\pi^2)}$$

leads to integrals of elementary functions for $S_1$ and $S_2$. However, the convergence of the integrals is bad (or at least Mathematica has trouble computing them numerically) and so I haven't been able to confirm the numerical value with sufficient accuracy. So I invite anyone else to check this other way to obtain a better closed form.

Comment: Your answer seems to me as an article, I am going to need a week to understand it! Many thanks :)

Comment: See the first section of this wikipedia article, which contains a useful method to recognize hypergeometric functions from a particular series https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function (the method I used here) @user243301

Comment: Many thanks for your perfect answer, I am going to study it.